# JPQL: direct query for a list of objects

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, java-10

We have an **Universe** and a **Funkopop**. We have made `@OneToMany` relation.

```
@Entity
public class Universe implements HasId{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer id;

    String name;

    @OneToMany
    List<FunkoPop> funkoPops = new ArrayList<>(); 

}



@Entity
public class FunkoPop implements HasId {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id = null;
    private String name;
    private boolean waterproof = false;
}
```

We want to list all funkopops in a universe.

```
var pops = em.createQuery("SELECT u.funkoPops FROM Universe u WHERE u.name = :universeName", 
                 FunkoPop.class)
                .setParameter("universeName", "Kung-Fury")
                .getResultList();
```

Unfortunately we have:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Type specified for TypedQuery [io.robusta.funko.entities.FunkoPop] is incompatible with 
query return type [interface java.util.Collection]
```

Comment: You can just use getSingleResult() instead of getResultList().

Comment: That is not what s/he is looking for: `u.funkoPops` in the query refers to a collection of elements of type `FunkoPop`.

Comment: You cannot select a MULTI-VALUED field in JPQL. Any JPA/JPQL docs would tell you that

Comment: Is this HQL? Change `em.createQuery(..., FunkoPop.class)` to `em.createQuery(..., Collection.class)` and see what you get as the result